# Variar el color de un range

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Hola tengo el siguiente range

[image: Range]

```js
var $sliders = $("input.slider");
$.each($sliders, function(i, elemento){
    tooltip: 'always';
    console.log(elemento.id);
    var slider = new Slider('#'+elemento.id, {
        formatter: function(value) {
            if(value >0 && value <=50) {
                return '' + value;
            }if(value>=51 && value <=80){
                return '' + value;
            }if(value>=81 && value <=100) {
                return '' + value;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.slider-selection {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, yellow, green);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>0%</label>
<input id="slider" class="slider" type="text"  data-slider-min="1" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="50"/>
<label>100%</label>
```

Utilice `linear-gradient(to right, red, yellow, green);` lo que quiero es que cuando llegue a por ejemplo 45% sea TODO el slider sea amarillo y vaya degradando a rojo conforme baje o vaya cambiando a verde según vaya subiendo el porcentaje en TODO el slider.

Comment: podrías poner el código que tienes hasta el momento? la parte significativa

Comment: Si pones el código que tienes sería más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: @EdgarGutiérrez  perdón por tardar en poner el código pero ya esta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta algo como esto (respondí antes de que modificaras tu pregunta)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
</head>
<style>
  input[type=range] {
    margin: auto;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0;
    width: 640px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #dedede;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #ff1100), color-stop(100%, #ff1100));
    background-size: 50% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
  }

  input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
  }


  input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    border: 0;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #777;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -webkit-appearance: none;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="1" />
</body>

<script>
  $('input[type=range]').on('input', function (e) {
    var min = e.target.min,
      max = e.target.max,
      val = e.target.value;
    if (val < 34) {
      $(e.target).css({
        'background-image': '-webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, red), color-stop(100%, red))'
      });
    }
    if (val > 34 && val < 64) {      
      $(e.target).css({
        'background-image': 'linear-gradient(to right, red , yellow)'
      });
    } 
    if (val > 64) {      
      $(e.target).css({
        'background-image': 'linear-gradient(to right, red , yellow,green)'
      });
    }


    $(e.target).css({
      'backgroundSize': (val - min) * 100 / (max - min) + '% 100%'
    });
  }).trigger('input');
</script>

</html>
```

Puedes verlo funcionando aqui:

```js
  $('input[type=range]').on('input', function (e) {
    var min = e.target.min,
      max = e.target.max,
      val = e.target.value;
    if (val < 34) {
      $(e.target).css({
        'background-image': '-webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, red), color-stop(100%, red))'
      });
    }
    if (val > 34 && val < 64) {      
      $(e.target).css({
        'background-image': 'linear-gradient(to right, red , yellow)'
      });
    } 
    if (val > 64) {      
      $(e.target).css({
        'background-image': 'linear-gradient(to right, red , yellow,green)'
      });
    }


    $(e.target).css({
      'backgroundSize': (val - min) * 100 / (max - min) + '% 100%'
    });
  }).trigger('input');
```

```css
input[type=range] {
    margin: auto;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0;
    width: 640px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #dedede;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #ff1100), color-stop(100%, #ff1100));
    background-size: 50% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
  }

  input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
  }


  input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    border: 0;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #777;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -webkit-appearance: none;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="1" />
```

Comment: Puedes explicar lo que hiciste y que fue lo que cambiaste?

Comment: Contesté antes de que publicara su codigo, pero lo que hace es una condición del "value" y asigna el color

Comment: Faltó el efecto de degradado

Comment: @GermanAlzate gracias por el aporte lo intentaré hacer de esa manera aunque no hace el efecto de degradado.

Comment: Gracias por la observación, ya agregué el degradado

Comment: @HugoQuiñónez acabo de editar la pregunta porque no me explique muy bien.

Comment: Ya revisaste los cambios que publiqué? https://plnkr.co/edit/Lg7ITWgEAaCCpFjgNS4v?p=preview

Comment: He colocado el código del enlace en la respuesta de Hugo Martínez. Podrías revisarlo @LuisMiguel.